# Generate Random Strings (with millons of characters) in excel

Tags: random, generator

I am looking for an add-in for Microsoft Excel 2013, that can generate a truly random string of any characters (millions of them), especially (A-Z) (a-z) (0-9). Please let me know what add-in to install or command I can use in Excel 2013 to do this task. The RAND and RANDBETWEEN functions return bigints, not numbers (or strings in this case), so they will probably not work. Thanks.

Comment: "truly random" -- you mean like quantum mechanics?

Answer (score 2):

You could write your own function. It won't be truly random, or even cryptographically secure, but it might be useful. Something like:

```
Function RandChars(n As Long, Optional alphabet As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789") As String
    Dim chars() As String
    Dim i As Long, k As Long
    k = Len(alphabet)
    ReDim chars(1 To n)
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        For i = 1 To n
            chars(i) = Mid(alphabet, .RandBetween(1, k), 1)
        Next i
    End With
    RandChars = Join(chars, "")
End Function
```

If this is entered into a standard VBA code module and you put the formula

`=RandChars(10)` in the range `A1:A10` you will get something like:

[image]

If you want something which is cryptographically secure, you need to replace `RandBetween` by a cryptographically secure PRNG.

Comment: Just on a related note, CSPRNGs are tricky to work with. They produce byte values (between 0 and 255) and in order to keep the output as random there is much more math involved. For example if you need a random value between 0 and 2, to use the least amount of entropy you would need to extract 2 bits and if it equals 3 (11) you would need to throw those bits away and check the next 2 bits, and so on, otherwise the randomness is compromised. This is too easy to get wrong, and uniquely it would be a logic error that will never produce unexpected output so can also be very difficult to detect.

Comment: @JonathanGray ```They produce byte values``` - Not in general. MersenneTwister for example produces 32 or 64 bits. ```it would be a logic error that will never produce unexpected output so can also be very difficult to detect``` - If it would never produce unexpected output, than it's random (because that's what we expected). No problem then. And while your *acceptance-sampling* approach is not wrong, no scientific-library is doing this (because it's just not needed to obtain good enough random values). Usually we don't care about maximizing the randomness given entropy because PRNGS are fast

Comment: 32 and 64 are both multiples of 8 so that only reinforces my statement that they only produce byte values. This translates to either 4 or 8 bytes. However I must offer a rebuttal to your argument that somewhat random is random enough. If used for cryptographic purposes, any flaw in the CSPRNG or the way it is used can realistically introduce a potential attack vector. CSPRNGs are specifically used when regular (fast) PRNGs are not enough. Since I've worked with CSPRNGs myself and know how tricky they can be to use correctly I decided to offer my insight. This is far from acceptance-sampling.

Comment: @sascha I forgot to tag you... Also I think you may be confused as to what a CSPRNG is or maybe you misread. After a quick Google search I found that Mersenne Twister is not cryptographically secure (at least in its native form). FYI a logic error is still a logic error whether it produces expected output or not.

Comment: @JonathanGray I didn't see that you are talking about crypto-PRNGS. My bad. Be sure that i understand that stuff (but like i said: i misread). Also: your bit-tricks described a really just a simple form of acceptance-sampling. Of course there is much more interesting stuff possible in the task of randomness-extraction (inlcuding beautiful theoretic stuff like expander-graphs) but that's not that relevant here. One could argue about other stuff you mentioned, but without a formal-model it's tedious. Sorry for the misleading comments!

Comment: Looks like there is a RNGCryptoServiceProvider Class for .NET.  [This article](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=176530) shows how to use a .NET class in VBA/Excel

Comment: @RonRoyston It makes sense that there is such a thing, though I have had mixed success in using .Net classes in VBA. For example, arraylists work nicely but hashtables don't. It isn't clear what OP really needs. They mentioned things like `Randbetween`, so this sort of thing might be enough.

Answer (score 0):

`=ROUND(RAND(),0)` in a cell produces a 0 or 1 randomly.  Do that in 8 cells.  Concatenate the individual 8 cells into a single string.  Do `=BIN2DEC()` on it.  That gives you a random number between 0 and 255.  `=RANDBETWEEN(0,255)` does the same thing.

Does that help you?  Simply figure out how many digits you want then generate the randum numbers to assign.

Comment: What advantage does this have over `RANDBETWEEN(0,255)`?

Answer (score 0):

The code below fills in the entire spreadsheet with random numbers.

```
function myFunction() {

function randnumber() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheet1");
var range = sheet.getRange("A1:Z10");
for (var x = 1; x <= range.getWidth(); x++) {
for (var y = 1; y <= range.getHeight(); y++) {
  var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8999999999) + 1000000000;
  range.getCell(y, x).setValue(number);
    }
  }

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheet1");
 var entries = [{
 name : "Numbers: 1-9",
 functionName : "numbers19"
   }];
 }
```